# Trying to get characters of each line separately and get NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, string

Trying to get characters of each line separately but whatever i try it say
java.lang.NullPointerException.

The strings in txt file have some empty spaces.("  ")

```
while ((line = scn.readLine()) != null){
    line2[a] = line;
    for (int l = 0; l < x; l++){
        chars[a][l] = new Character(line.charAt(l));
    }
}
```

The txt file is:

```
  ###############################
  #      #    #      #          #
  # #### # #### #### # ######## #
  # #    # #       # #        # #
  # # #### # ##### # ######## # #
  # # #    #   #   #        # # #
  # # # ###### # #### ##### # # #
  # # # #   #  #    # #   # # # #
  # #   # # # ##### # # # #   # #
  # ### # # # # * # # # # # ### #
  #   # # # # ## ## # # # # #   #
  ### # # # #  # #  # # # # # ###
  #   # # # ## # # ## # # # #   #
  # ### # #  # # # #  # # # # # #
  # #   # #### # # # ## # #   # #
  # # # #      # #####  ####### #
  # # #   ######                #
  # #######    ##################
  #                             #
  ##############-################
```

I fixed it ,but still the result isnt proper.
Thats what i get:

```
 ####################
 #          #       #
 # ######## # ##### #
 # #      #   #   # #
 # # #### ##### ### #
 # # #            # #
 #   # ########## # #
 ##### #          # #
 #     # ####### ## #
 # #####       # #  #
 # #   ####### # #  #
 # # # #     ### #  # 
 ### #   ###     #  #
 #   ##### ######## #
 # # #   #*       # -
 # # # # # ###### # #
 # #   # ###    # # #
 # #####     #### # #
 #     #######  # # #
 #####         ## # #
```

Comment: please add programming language tag you are using

Comment: show an example .txt file. show more code that shows what your variables are

Comment: In short... `line` is `null`. Debug your code to know why.

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop does not test for when it reaches the end of the file, so line becomes null:

```
while((line= scn.readLine())!=null){
  line2[a]=line;
  for(int l=0;l<line.length;l++){
  chars[a][l]=new Character(line.charAt(l));
  }
}
```

Please don't ask questions relating to or encourage questions asking why NullPointerExceptions happen with a particular piece of code.  There are tens of thousands of these artifacts polluting stackoverflow, and they are of almost no value to anyone.

Comment: @EricLeschinski, Totally agreed.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the things that can cause NullPointer from the given code snippet:

1. `scn` not initialized - Make sure that you have done this.
2. `line2` not initialized
3. `chars[a]` not initialized. 
   Try fixing those and you should be good to go.